# Does `fs.createReadStream` set the default end value to the current end of a file?

Tags: node.js, fs

I am reading a file that's being written to. So I have:

```
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file, {start:0});
```

from my testing, it looks like `fs.createReadStream` will put a value for {end:number} where the end of the read stream is the current end of the file. In theory, however as the stream reads data from the file, it could keep reading until the *new* end of the file (as new data is being written during the read).

Does anyone know for sure how this is implemented?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `autoClose: false` to prevent the automatic close:

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

> If autoClose is false, then the file descriptor won't be closed, even
>   if there's an error. It is the application's responsibility to close
>   it and make sure there's no file descriptor leak. If autoClose is set
>   to true (default behavior), on 'error' or 'end' the file descriptor
>   will be closed automatically.

Comment: upvoted but it's not just about the auto close tmk, it's about telling it to keep reading since the end of the file may have changed since it was first opened for reading? something like that